# Adding PHP to dynamically created div content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making a website with a submenu, which renders content to a div. The website is powered by Wordpress, and this part of the site is a plugin I've made. I want the content of the div to fetch info from database, i.e. I want to add PHP code. Can't seem to add any PHP though. If I make the loaded content a PHP file, it doesn't work due to the `jQuery('#pageContent').html(msg)` in the JS, and if I add PHP code to a HTML file, that code doesn't seem to be recognised. What would be the way to do this? I should perhaps add that the PHP I want to add is to be part of a form and as far as I can see needs to be in the same file as the HTML.

Here is the JS function with Ajax to load content:

```
function loadPage(url)  //the function that loads pages via AJAX
{   
    url=url.replace('#page','');    //strip the #page part of the hash and leave only the page number

    jQuery('#loading').css('visibility','visible');  //show the rotating gif animation   

    jQuery.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'ajax_request2',
            page: url //with the page number as a parameter
        },
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, textError) { 
            console.log(textError);
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            window.alert("Working loadPage ajax!");
            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)    //if no errors
            {
                jQuery('#pageContent').html(msg);    //load the returned html into pageContent
                jQuery('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');   //and hide the rotating gif
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I think the OP already knows that part, i think the OP's problem is there is no response

Comment: check your network tab in your browser to see and examine the response, maybe its an error 500 or 404 if its calling the wrong url API, by the way, what response are you expecting anyway? a markup html or a digit or some sort?

Comment: @Ingrid: Can you elaborate more on this: "If I make the loaded content a PHP file, it doesn't work due to the `jQuery('#pageContent').html(msg)`". How does it not work? What did the PHP file return?

Comment: You may use network monitoring feature of developer tools on [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) or [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) to check the actual data returned by your AJAX request.

Comment: I think @HarunYilmaz was probably right in writing his (deleted) comment, if it isn't possible to render PHP code with JS in the way I am trying? Don't know how to make the content of the div act the way I want otherwise though. (Collecting content from database to be shown in an html select dropdown)

Comment: @KoalaYeung So if I for instance have a really simple PHP file added to the div: `<?php `echo 'x';`?>`, nothing shows up on the web page. But now I see that it's treated like an html comment - what's actually returned is `<!-- ?php echo 'x'; ?-->`.

Comment: Do you mean your PHP file at the path `ajax_object.ajax_url` has only 1 line: `<?php echo 'x'; ?>`?

Comment: @KoalaYeung Yes, at the moment, for testing. :)

Comment: So if you go to the URL of that PHP file, it should show you `x`, right? You may open the source view to confirm it. If it is not, you might have a serious setup issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200382/discussion-between-ingrid-and-koala-yeung).

Answer (score 0):

I modified your function a little bit and directed it to a test site for JSON data. This little snippet works. Maybe it is helpful to you?

As the test site only returns JSON the "html" I put into `#pageContent` is not really html, but I hope you get the point nonetheless.

If you want to know what Ajax returned then you can always insert a `console.log(msg)` in the right place (see the commented-out line below).

And - just to be clear - if your loaded content is to be generated by a PHP script, then the url in your loadPage function should of course point to a PHP script on the relevant server. This script will look for the data and process it into your desired html format before sending it back as the response to the Ajax request.

```js
function loadPage(url){   
    url=url.replace('#page',''); //strip the #page part of the hash and leave only the page number
    jQuery('#IAmloading').show();  //show the rotating gif animation   
    jQuery.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: url, // the URL of the page to be loaded ...
        data: {action: 'ajax_request2', id: 4},  //your further parameters ...
        dataType: "json",                            //expect json to be returned
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, textError) { console.log(textError);},
        success: function(msg){ console.log("Working loadPage ajax!");
            // console.log(msg);  // show what the AJAX request returned
            if(msg)    //if no errors
            {
                
                jQuery('#pageContent').html(JSON.stringify(msg));  //put msg into pageContent
                jQuery('#IAmloading').hide();   //and hide the rotating gif
            }
        }
    });
}

// call the function with the URL of a test site (returns JSON only ...):
loadPage('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
```

```css
#IAmloading {visibility: hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="IAmloading">Please wait, page is loading ...</div>
<div id="pageContent"></div>
```

Comment: I added the `console.log`, which gave me the correct php code. Although when inspecting the html, the php code is commented out. Perhaps the php file is in the wrong folder for Wordpress... Don't know where it should go though.